# How to call a function at start and end of building a target in cmake

Tags: cmake, cmake-custom-command

I'm looking for a way to execute shell code when starting and finishing the build of a target in cmake.  The final goal is to send a message to a data tracking tool indicating when builds start and finish.

So for example, if "make" build targets alpha, beta and gamma, I'd like to call foo_begin() when alpha starts building and foo_end when target alpha is successfully built, and so on for all the targets.

Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like you want the secondary "build events" variant of `add_custom_commands`

Comment: I have answered your question directly, but if you gave us more detail about what you're actually trying to accomplish, we (I) could give you a better, more pointed answer. "Execute code" isn't a goal, it's a step to a goal.

Answer (score 0):

It is *not* possible to call arbitrary CMake functions at build time. Once the build system is generated, all the normal variable state and function definitions are discarded (i.e. they are not in cache). The `COMMAND` argument to `add_custom_command` takes a shell command, not a CMake function.

However, you can use CMake's script mode, so if what you want is to use CMake as a scripting language just to implement some build hooks, you can do this:

Let's create a file called `proc_target.cmake` with these contents:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)

if (PRE_BUILD)
  message(STATUS "PRE_BUILD: ${TARGET}")
else ()
  message(STATUS "POST_BUILD: ${TARGET}")
endif ()
```

Now in the CMakeLists.txt we can write:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(example)

add_executable(foo main.cpp)

add_custom_command(
  TARGET foo PRE_BUILD
  COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}"
          -DTARGET=foo
          -DPRE_BUILD=1
          -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/proc_target.cmake"
)

add_custom_command(
  TARGET foo POST_BUILD
  COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}"
          -DTARGET=foo
          -DPRE_BUILD=0
          -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/proc_target.cmake"
)
```

Then when you run this build, you'll see the following commands:

```
$ cmake -G Ninja -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
...
$ cmake --build build -- -nv
[1/2] /usr/bin/c++   -O3 -DNDEBUG -MD -MT CMakeFiles/foo.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/foo.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/foo.dir/main.cpp.o -c /path/to/main.cpp
[2/2] cd /path/to/build && /usr/bin/cmake -DTARGET=foo -DPRE_BUILD=1 -P /path/to/proc_target.cmake && cd /path/to/build && /usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG  CMakeFiles/foo.dir/main.cpp.o -o foo   && cd /path/to/build && /usr/bin/cmake -DTARGET=foo -DPRE_BUILD=0 -P /path/to/proc_target.cmake
```

You can see how `proc_target.cmake` is called twice: once just before and once just after invoking the linker for `foo`. If you want `proc_target` to run before any of the sources are compiled, then you would want to write:

```
add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT pre-foo.stamp
  COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}"
          -DTARGET=foo
          -DPRE_BUILD=1
          -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/proc_target.cmake"
  COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E touch pre-foo.stamp
  DEPENDS "$<TARGET_PROPERTY:foo,SOURCES>"
)
add_custom_target(pre-foo DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/pre-foo.stamp")
add_dependencies(foo pre-foo)
```

instead of the `PRE_BUILD` custom command above. Then you would get:

```
[1/3] cd /path/to/build && /usr/bin/cmake -DTARGET=foo -DPRE_BUILD=1 -P /path/to/proc_target.cmake
[2/3] /usr/bin/c++   -O3 -DNDEBUG -MD -MT CMakeFiles/foo.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/foo.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/foo.dir/main.cpp.o -c /path/to/main.cpp
[3/3] : && /usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG  CMakeFiles/foo.dir/main.cpp.o -o foo   && cd /path/to/build && /usr/bin/cmake -DTARGET=foo -DPRE_BUILD=0 -P /path/to/proc_target.cmake
```

And now you can see that the custom target `pre-foo` is processed before `foo`.

This is most likely *not* what you want, however. It's over-engineered. If you want to generate a source file for a target, you should use `add_custom_command(OUTPUT)` directly and attach the output to the target as a source file (i.e. when you call `add_executable` or via `target_sources`).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  In fact, running something from the shell is what I desire, I'll clarify the

Answer (score 0):

Per @botje's comment, it seems I need cmake's add_custom_command with build event specifies.  I will however need PRE_BUILD, which the documentation informs me is only available for vs-studio, while I am building use cmake & gcc.  So I guess I have a new question:  how to duplicate the behavior of PRE_BUILD in a cmake/gcc build environment.

Comment: "So I guess I have a new question: how to duplicate the behavior of PRE_BUILD in a cmake/gcc build environment." -- my answer shows this with the `add_custom_target` solution at the end.